# For which positive integers $n$ does there exist a positive integer $m_n<n$ such that $\gcd(n, m_n)=\gcd(n,k), 0<k<n \implies m_n=k$?

Tags: number-theory

For which positive integers $n$ does there exist a positive integer $m_n<n$ such that $\gcd(n , m_n)=\gcd(n,k), 0<k<n \implies m_n=k$?

For example $(4,1)=(4,3)=1,(4,2)=2$ so $n=4$ is such a positive integer where we can take $m_4=2$ . ( I need this for a generalization of the result in this question [A question on Groups and its center](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842369/a-question-on-groups-and-its-center) )

Answer (score 1):

just for even numbers $m_n$ exists. for prove this statement it is obvious that for even numbers if you set $m_n=\frac{n}{2}$, $m_n$ will have the property that we want.

now suppose that $n$ is odd now. if there exists such $m_n$ then we will have

$$m_n = d \cdot m'$$
$$n = d \cdot n'$$
that $n'$ and $m'$ are coprime numbers. know $d$ and $(n'-1).d$ are two distinct numbers that their gcd with $n$ is $d$ too.

Comment: $\text{gcd}(49,7)=\text{gcd}(49,14)=\text{gcd}(49,21)=\text{gcd}(49,28)=\text{gcd}(49,35)=7$.

Comment: do you mean to say $(n , (n'-1)d)=1$ ?

Comment: no! i say that $(n,(n'-1)d)=d$